# Simplifying expressions involving unit vectors?

Tags: vectors

Say I have two unit vectors, A, and B. What is the most simplified version of the expression

$$\vec{B} \times (\vec{B} \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B}))$$

I know that given three vectors $\vec{A}, \vec{B}, \vec{C}$,

$$\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C}) = (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{C})\vec{B} - (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B})\vec{C}$$

but I am slightly unsure of what to do after the initial substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simply the expression $\vec{B} \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B})$. We have

$$\vec{B} \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) = (\vec{B}\cdot \vec{B})\vec{A} - (\vec{B} \cdot \vec{A})\vec{B}.$$

Thus, by the distributive property of cross products,

$$\vec{B}\times (\vec{B}\times (\vec{A}\times \vec{B})) = (\vec{B}\cdot \vec{B})\vec{B}\times \vec{A} - (\vec{B}\cdot \vec{A})\vec{B}\times \vec{B} = (\vec{B} \cdot \vec{B})\vec{B}\times \vec{A},$$

where the last step follows from $\vec{B}\times \vec{B} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

In your known identity,

$$\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C) = 
   (\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B - (\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C,$$

substitute $\vec B$ for $\vec A$:

$$\vec B \times (\vec B \times \vec C) = 
   (\vec B \cdot \vec C)\vec B - (\vec B \cdot \vec B)\vec C.$$

Now substitute $\vec A \times \vec B$ for $\vec C$:

$$\vec B \times (\vec B \times (\vec A \times \vec B)) = 
   (\vec B \cdot (\vec A \times \vec B))\vec B
    - (\vec B \cdot \vec B)(\vec A \times \vec B).$$

You can simplify this using the fact that 
$\vec B \cdot (\vec A \times \vec B) = 0.$